# How to kill a process and all its threads from command line in linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, kill

I have a shell script myscript.sh. When I run it, it spawns 7 threads.
Now I tried to kill it using the command `pgrep myscript | awk '{system("kill "$1)}'`.

The process is killed but still the threads keep running. 
So how to kill the process and all its threads from command line in linux?

Comment: All threads have the same PID in Linux. Do you really mean thread or do you mean child processes?

Comment: Please include the code so that it is clear what your script is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

***`sudo pkill $PROCESS_NAME`***

to kill the process completely. The process name can be found using the `top` command under the COMMAND column.